# Need to generate sequence ids without using groupby in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to generate Sequence of Numbers column(Seq_No) as Product_IDs changes in table. In my input table I have only Product_IDs and want output with Seq_No. We can not use GropuBy or Row Number over partition in SQL as Scala does not support.

```
    Logic : Seq_No = 1 
            for(i = 2:No_of_Rows)
             when Product_IDs(i) != Product_IDs(i-1) then Seq_No(i) = Seq_No(i-1)+1
             Else Seq_No(i) = Seq_No(i-1)
             end as Seq_No

Product_IDs Seq_No
ID1           1
ID1           1
ID1           1
ID2           2
ID3           3
ID3           3
ID3           3
ID3           3
ID1           4
ID1           4
ID4           5
ID5           6
ID3           7
ID6           8
ID6           8
ID5           9
ID5           9
ID4          10
```

So I want to generate Seq_No as current Product_Id is not equal to previous Product_Ids. Input table has only one column Product_IDs and we want Product_IDs with Seq_No using Spark Scala.

Comment: @ Alberto Bonsanto, I want to increase Seq_No by 1 as Product_IDs changes from one row to another.

Comment: Please edit your question and be more explicit

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just write a function to generate the sequence numbers:

```
scala> val getSeqNum: String => Int = {
  var prevId = ""
  var n = 0
  (id: String) => {
    if (id != prevId) {
      n += 1
      prevId = id
    }
    n
  }
}
getSeqNum: String => Int = <function1>

scala> for { id <- Seq("foo", "foo", "bar") } yield getSeqNum(id)
res8: Seq[Int] = List(1, 1, 2)
```

UPDATE:

I'm not quite clear on what you want beyond that, Nikhil, and I am not a Spark expert, but I imagine you want something like

```
val rrd = ???  // Hopefully you know how to get the RRD
for {
  (id, col2, col3) <- rrd  // assuming the entries are tuples
  seqNum = getSeqNum(id)
} yield ???  // Hopefully you know how to transform the entries
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can you please help me how to pass column from dataframe  in for loop. For this example, how to pass Product_IDs in for loop?

Comment: @Tzach Zohar Can you please help me to solve this original questions?

Comment: Nikhil, I don't know who Tzach Zohar is, but did I answer your original question about how to assign the IDs?

Comment: @ AmigoNico, thanks for your answer but i have dataframe and I don't know how to convert column which will fit into function you have written.